# not able to replace \n using regex_replace in pyspark

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace all "\n" characters present in a string column in pyspark. I tried the following which seems not to work

```
df1 = df.withColumn("old_trial_text_clean", f.regexp_replace(f.col("old_trial_text"), "[\\n]", ""))
```

The current dataframe has the exact same text in both column

```
old_trial_text_clean
'', 'Drug: \n\n. Other Names:\n\n ', '\n\n. Other Names:\n\n ', 'Drug: \n\n. Other Names:\n\n \n\n\n\n. Other Names:\n\n ' , 'Arms\n. Assigned Interventions\n\n\n \n\n\n Drug: \n\n. Other Names:\n\n \n\n\n\n \n\n\n \n\n. Other Names:\n\n \n\n\n\n +ALN plus alendronate\n\n\n Drug: \n\n. Other Names:\n\n \n\n\n\n. Other Names:\n\n ', '', '', '+ALN plus alendronate'
old_trial_text
'', 'Drug: \n\n. Other Names:\n\n ', '\n\n. Other Names:\n\n ', 'Drug: \n\n. Other Names:\n\n \n\n\n\n. Other Names:\n\n ' , 'Arms\n. Assigned Interventions\n\n\n \n\n\n Drug: \n\n. Other Names:\n\n \n\n\n\n \n\n\n \n\n. Other Names:\n\n \n\n\n\n +ALN plus alendronate\n\n\n Drug: \n\n. Other Names:\n\n \n\n\n\n. Other Names:\n\n ', '', '', '+ALN plus alendronate'
```

Can someone please let me know what am I missing. I want all the \n characters to be replaced in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the backslash in a literal newline `\n`.  Use this version:

```
df1 = df.withColumn("old_trial_text_clean", f.regexp_replace(f.col("old_trial_text"), "\n", ""))
```

Comment: I tried the above
```df1 = df.withColumn("old_trial_text_clean", f.regexp_replace(f.col("old_trial_text"), "\n", ""))
display(df1.select("old_trial_text_clean","old_trial_text").where(f.col("old_trial_text").contains("\\n")))```. Still I have the same output. In the display statement I have to escape the \n to display those rows.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the above issue I had to use the following regex

```
df1 = df.withColumn("old_trial_text_clean", f.regexp_replace(f.col("old_trial_text"),"\\\\n" ,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is looking for a modern solution to this problem:

```py
df.select(
    F.translate(F.col("old_trial_text_clean"), "\n", " ").alias("old_trial_text_clean")
)
```